# How to interpret Quotas for Google Services

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a Sheets add-on that makes an API call to an external URL. The external application is taking more than six minutes to respond. At six minutes, we hit the script runtime per execution limit  (as specified at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas ) and fail.  The external application's API does not take callback functions for asynchronous processing, so we want to understand what account has to be upgraded to get the 30 minute execution limit instead of 6. Is it we, the provider of the add-on, who upgrade our own account to Business, for a cost of $10/month? Or is it each user of the add-on who has to have Business Edition or better, at a much higher cost of $10/user/month? We asked this question at the G Suite Help Forum and were referred to ask it at stackoverflow.

Comment: Probably user..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: The User (not the maker of the add-on).

The way add-ons work is to do with which account (i.e. "user" account) is invoking it's services / functions and accordingly, regardless of the architecture of the code / add-on script, it is the user against whom the quota limit would be applicable.

Plus, just worked on an add-on on a G Suite domain where I was presented with exactly this scenario - tested this both ways and concluded that the users ought to be on a 30 min. threshold and not the maker of add-ons.

Hope this helps.